# ¿Cómo puedo usar las funcionalidades de una página sin usar WebServices?

Tags: java, web

Probablemente el título no se entienda muy bien, pero este es el tema, hay unas páginas Web la cual brindan información colocando un dato específico y un código 'CAPTCHA', como ejemplo colocar el documento de identidad de una persona y que este arroje datos principales como ("nombres","apellidos", etc). Pero sin la necesidad de usar un WebService o API. Estoy iniciando con JAVA WEB y quisiera saber si esto es posible, que temas debo averiguar y todo eso para poder lograrlo, de que mi sistema(WEB) ingrese dicho dato(solo ese dato, evadiendo el 'CAPTCHA' y poder extraer toda la información posible.

-- Añado detalles a mi consulta

Cuento con este link;
https://e-consultaruc.sunat.gob.pe/cl-ti-itmrconsruc/jcrS00Alias
que me abre la siguiente pantalla.

[image: Pantalla]

La cual me brinda información, pero ese link o URL no es un WebService.
Hay manera de interactuar con ella desde una aplicación externa?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé si te he entendido bien, pero si lo que quieres es acceder a un servidor web ya existente, las formas de acceder a él son precisamente las que el servidor provea.

Es decir, depende del interfaz que te proporcione el servidor.

Comment: Replantearé un poco mi pregunta.

Comment: ¿Tal vez te refieras a hacer un programa que simule ser un ser humano interactuando directamente con la página web mostrada? 
Sería posible determinar cómo construir una petición POST con los datos necesarios, pero en esencia eso es un bot y los captchas se crearon precisamente para impedir el uso de bots. Tendrías que resolver el captcha con tu programa. Y si lo logras, seguro que google te recompensa sobradamente ;P

Comment: Eso mismo es lo que quiero XD, seguramente el problema sería el CAPTCHA, pero por ahora veré como construir una petición POST.